# wpf tooltip on mouseover and mouseout

Tags: wpf, tooltip, mouseevent

What I am trying to do is have the tool tip show once a mouse over occurs.  The ToolTip will not turn off until a mouse out.

Only a mouse out will allow the ToolTip to close.

The customer has a requirement where they want the ToolTip to stay up indefinite until a mouse out happens.

Additional:  Is there a way only to close the tooltip on mouse out, and not mouse move?

The area that the mouse will be over is a rectangle and only when I move out of the rectangle should the tool tip close.

Thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your question isn't completely clear, and I'm not sure what you're looking for, but the things that will affect ToolTip duration follow:

`ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay` - Length of time in milliseconds between hovering over a control and when the tooltip appears.  0 = instant.

`ToolTipService.ShowDuration` - Length of time in milliseconds a tooltip will hang around while the mouse is over it.  Setting it really high will be effectively a "never turn off" option, but there isn't a true always option.

`ToolTipService.BetweenShowDelay` - Once a tooltip pops up, this is the amount of time that must pass before `InitialShowDelay` is again observed.

Example:

```
<TextBox ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="5000" 
ToolTipService.ShowDuration="2000" 
ToolTipService.BetweenShowDelay="10000" 
ToolTip="This is a tool tip." />
```

With this, when you hover over the TextBox, a tooltip will show up after five seconds.  It will hang around for two seconds.  And until you haven't looked at a tooltip for 10 seconds, there will be no delay between hover and pop-up.

Comment: What I am trying to have it do is once a mouse over the ToolTip will not turn off until a mouse out.  Only a mouse out will allow the ToolTip to close.  That is what I am trying to do.  I hope that is clearer.  The customer has a requirement where they want the ToolTip to stay up indefinite until a mouse out happens.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, then I think the best you can do is make the ShowDuration REALLY big.  If you do 360,000,000, that'll last 100 hours, which is a long time for a mouse cursor to stay in one place.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way only to close it on mouse out and not mouse move?  The area is a rectangle and only when I move out of the rectangle should the tool tip close.  Thanks again.

Comment: In my test project I set up to look at this, the tooltip stays up as long as the cursor stays within the control that has the tooltip. So on the TextBox sample, as long as the mouse doesn't leave the TextBox once the tooltip comes up, the tooltip shouldn't go anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

If you just set `ToolTip="Message"`. Your message will be shown only when the mouse is on the control.